# How can I place the 3 circles so that the center of overlap of them is always in screen center on different screen size?

Tags: android, layout

I'm going to implement a UI design like the picture in this link (please ignore all text and coordinate in the picture): https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=a9a5b8b663e8f93a!25425&authkey=!AClrIvht7LiHDPg&ithint=folder%2cpng

There are 3 circles with the same radius, and 3 circles have overlap where the center of overlap is the screen center. Circle A align parent top and B align parent bottom and left. C is symmetric of B. My question is how can I scale the coordinate of 3 circles and the radius so that on different size of screens it always looks the same? I need to calculate these values on different size of screens:

1. top margin of circle A
2. left margin of circle B
3. bottom margin of circle B
4. radius of circle

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can get the size of your screen, and then set the position of the circles by %

Comment: Do you need those circles to be separate views? Or can they be a part of one view that fills the entire screen?

Comment: @blipinsk, I need to place in separate views